# What's with the strange account icons?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've been noticing lately that certain users (myself included) have been given different account pictures when displayed as a small icon:

[image]

The account pictures are alright on the profile pages, but when posting answers and questions, this icon appears. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's just a temporary issue with retrieving your image from [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) -- that's their logo.